# How to use LINQ to do simple DB query?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

Below is how I have been doing data access in `.NET 2.0`.  How should I do this using **LINQ** in `.NET 4.0`?

```
Dim dt As DataTable
Using oDB As OleDbConnection = GetDbConnection()
    oDB.Open()
    Using oCmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 = @id", oDB)
    oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", UserId)
    oDB.Open()
    dt = New DataTable()
        Using da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(oCmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
Msgbox "Surname: " + dt.Rows(0)("Surname")
```

Comment: Are  you sure this is a good question for Stackoverflow? You should just read some tutorials on `LINQ to Entities`

Comment: Get Started with Entity Framework (EF) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907

Comment: Not interested in Entities. It is a pre-existing database that I am accessing.

Comment: Why do you think there is anything wrong with doing it this way?  What improvements are you hoping to get from using LINQ?

Comment: Well then read a tutorial how to use the `Enterprise Library` with SQL Commands. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647630.aspx

Comment: @LoztInSpace: I want to learn it and wouldn't it be fewer lines of code?

Comment: How do you learn something when somebody is making the code for you? Stackoverflow is for problems and discussion and not for tutorials.

Comment: @CJ7:  I think you are misunderstanding something.  In order to use LINQ to query your database, you will need to use a LINQ Provider.  [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) and [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) are two popular providers available.  Also, it isn't about "fewer lines of code".  There are much huger benefits.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

var query = (from u in db.table1 where u.Column1 == id select u).FirstOrDefault;
```

Comment: why `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: to ensure that only one record will be returned

Comment: but where does OP say that he want that? :) I read the question like he wants a collection (`da.Fill(dt)`)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would perform the query if you were using [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx):

```
using(var context = new MyEntities())
{
    var result = context.Table1.Where(x => x.Column1 == id);
}
```

You could also consider starting with [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Entity Framework must be installed on your machine. You will have to add the Entity Model in your projects. It will automatically map all the database tables into classes by using a internal Visual Studio tool. Then you have to retrieve data like.

Suppose there is a table `Employee` in you database which is mapped to `Employee` class in your .net project.

You will have to use following code for getting employees having age less than 45, where `Age` is an attribute of your `Employee` table. It will be automatically mapped as the property of your `Employee` class.

Here we go.

```
using(var _entities = new MyDBEntities())
{
   //LINQ query
   var query = from emp in _entities.Employees //Employees is the collection of Employee
               where emp.Age < 45
               select emp;

  //query object will be containing all the employees in the form of collection whose age is
  // less than 45
}
```